# Pass Parameters of different datatypes to a Golang Variadic function

Tags: function, go, variadic-functions

I have the following Golang `main` function where another variadic function `variadicFunc` is called to which I need to pass parameters of different datatypes. The code is as  follows.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    variadicFunc("hello", "Change", "the ", "World using Golang", 1, 2, 3, 4)
}

func variadicFunc(messages ...string) {
    for _, i := range messages {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

When running the program following error is thrown.

> Cannot use 1(type int) as type string in argument to variadicFunc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [interface](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces)

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() { 
  variadicFunc("hello", "Change", "the ", "World using Golang", 1, 2, 3, 4)
}

func variadicFunc(messages ...interface{}) {
  for _, i := range messages {
    fmt.Println(i)
  }
}
```

Comment: Brian Vanover :  When I use the  interface , I just get the memory address as the output printed instead of the parameter strings passed.

Comment: @CheralIrumborai, use the `fmt` package. The code above will work for you.